# How to write a function for multiple filtering a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

we have a data frame containing four features of dtype; num, num, object and float respectively.

And i want to filter data with this condition:
1. f['g']=< 53
2. f['h'] minmax (1,67)  ..the value should be between the user-specified value.
3. f['k]=='y'
4.f['l'] minmax(22,77)    ..the value should be between the user-specified value.

I want to write a function named 'Datafilter'  which can do multiple filtering and also we should be able to add filters and change conditions according to our future requirement.

Here is a Dataframe.

```
f= pd.DataFrame({'g':[1,2,3,45,33,57,23,53,56,79],   
'h':[12,344,5,78,98,95,43,56,32,23],
'k':['y','y','n','y','n','n','y','n','y','n'],
'l':[1.0,2.0,22.0,244.0,43.0,34.0,78.0,5.0,77.0,97.0]})
```

I am a beginner so I was able to do it by applying one filter at a time.

```
>>>[IN] t=f.copy()

>>>[IN] t=t[ t['g']<= 53]

>>>[IN] t=t[t['h'].between(12,98) & t['l'].between(2.0,78.0)]

>>>[IN] t=t[t['k']=='n']

>>>[IN] print(t)

>>>[OT] 

    g   h   k   l
4   33  98  n   43.0
7   53  56  n   5.0
```

the function should be generic i.e. reusable and should able to handle additional filters as well, in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can seimply do something like this.

```py
from typing import *
import pandas as pd

f= pd.DataFrame({'g':[1,2,3,45,33,57,23,53,56,79, 12],   
'h':[12,344,5,78,98,95,43,56,32,23, 33],
'k':['y','y','n','y','n','n','y','n','y','n', 'y'],
'l':[1.0,2.0,22.0,244.0,43.0,34.0,78.0,5.0,77.0,97.0,66]})

def Datafilter(df, h_minmax : List[int], l_minmax : List[int]) -> pd.DataFrame:
    return df[(df["g"] <= 53) & (df["h"].between(*h_minmax)) & (df["l"].between(*l_minmax)) & (df["k"] == "y")]

print(Datafilter(f, [1,67], [22,77]))
```

That will give you.

```py
     g  h   k   l
10  12  33  y   66
``
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use the `&` operator to apply all filters at the same time just as in

`t=t[(t['h'].between(12,98)) & (t['l'].between(2.0,78.0))]`.

You have to put each filter into round brackets else there will be an error.